# Issuing Command Via SSH Prompts for Password

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm having an issue with a script used in a project I inherited that has little to no documentation, and am in the process of documenting everything. I'm trying to debug an issue with one line of a script that is executed on the host machine to call out to a LAN-attached Raspberry Pi with SSH to return some information about the Pi.

We already have working versions of this Raspberry Pi which can execute the script without issue, and I'm not sure what the difference is. When executed on the new one, it prompts for the root password on the Pi, but it has not done this on previous versions of the device. I assume it has something to do with the SSH configuration but I don't know enough about SSH to say what would be the cause.

The line in particular causing the issue is:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {host_name} uname -a &>/dev/null
rc=$?       #gets the return value of the remote command so we can read the uname info
```

{host_name} of course is the actual host name it's connecting to, but I've left that part out for privacy reasons. The script is the same on both machines.

Both Pi devices are the same model and I'm having trouble narrowing down what could cause me to not be able to execute this command. Does anyone know what I need to configure in order to be able to execute this command on the Pi remotely?

Comment: Impossible to answer with the info at hand.  Do you have the same users on both Pis? If you do, does one of them have a dedicated `~/.ssh/config` entry on your local machine? If no, does the working one have a relevant entry in `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/*`? P.S.: I'm surprised the script does what you're asking, normally commands to be executed on the remote host need to be grouped with their parameters by quotes, e.g. `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {host_name} "uname -a" &>/dev/null` ...

Comment: Probably the first devices have the ssh keys setup by someone previously but this new device has not as you have not done it.

Comment: @tink Yes, same users on both devices, as the users are created by the same script. No, there is no "config" file in that directory for either Pi, just a known_hosts file, but there are several private and public keys in /etc/ssh. I'm currently copying these from the old one to the new one to see if that changes anything. It may be a sudoers problem, but I thought I had fixed that already.

Comment: You also mentioned `root` in the original post - are you really executing ssh commands as root?! ;)  Keep prodding. Btw, looking for keys in /etc/ssh is the wrong place, check root's `~/.ssh` for `authorized_keys` ...

Comment: The command is not being explicitly executed as root, but the ssh command only specifies the hostname, not the user, so it defaults to root. Also, as I said, there is nothing in ~/.ssh besides the known_hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some more digging around, I discovered that there was a separate .ssh directory under /root that contained an authorized_keys file. After copying this to the new Pi, it worked. I had been wondering all this time if there was a separate config folder for root, but I've never gone digging around /root, so I wasn't aware that it was there.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix:**

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  user@server
```

**Detailed fix:**

Most likely you would need to set up Async keys (public/Private) for proper passwordless login. Your command does not show you are using keys so I'm assuming you are not (e.g. -A or -i /path/to/key). Generally root user is blocked (I guess not your problem), I would set up another user for this or change sshd config. You could also Compare the sshd configurations between the Pi Boxes.

See: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/passwordless.md

Comment: Alright, that's something I could explore, but the whole point of this was to figure out why the original one doesn't need a password and to change the new one to reflect it. I would prefer not to alter the script and to figure out how the original one fixed this issue, since I'm supposed to be documenting the setup process, not changing it.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau we dont' have enough info. to answer your question :-( .. I would start by comparing the config files for ssh between the PI boxes . Can you share that information with us ?

Comment: As I mentioned above, there is no ~/.ssh/config. The only file in that directory is the known_hosts file.

Comment: After checking the sshd_config on both devices, one thing stood out. In the original device, the sshd_config file in /etc/ssh has a line that says "PermitRootLogin yes", while the new one has that line commented out, but it says "#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password". Could this be the issue?

Comment: try ssh -vv on the working system to see what it's doing

Comment: Oddly enough, executing SSH manually to try to connect to the older Pi using that same command (with -vv added), the one that works when the script is run, prompts me for the password for the user of the host machine, rather than root, but doesn't accept any of the passwords I entered, and shouldn't be asking for a password at all. Other than that, I'm not really sure what would be relevant in the output from the added -vv option.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau I have never touched PI but from an SSH perspective, if you don't use keys, you really have to open up the security to allow root to connect without password.  Just to give you some idea, you need to make changes to like 4 files.

Comment: Compare between the systems  cat /etc/passwd | grep root  and  cat /etc/shadow | grep root ,  and egrep -i "(root|empty)" /etc/ssh/sshd_config . maybe post them here. also when you ssh I assume you specify the user  root@ipaddress ?

Comment: There are keys in the /etc/ssh directory, as I said, but they're different between the old and new Pi, and I'm not sure if they should be the same or if it's just the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file that needs to be updated on the new Pi. No, I don't specify root. It assumes root. All I type is the alias for the host, which as I said, WORKS on the old Pi, but not the new one. I'll try the other things you mentioned.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau ok, the -vv output should have told you if the keys were being used on the old working system. If so then you can probably migrate them to the root user's account on the new system and update SSH config to allow key based login

Comment: And if I wanted to enable key-based login, would that be the "PermitRootLogin" property in sshd_config? Also, the root entry in /etc/passwd matches. As I've said before, though... the lines for PermitRootLogin and PermitEmptyPasswords are commented out on the new Pi.

Comment: I just tried ' PermitRootLogin yes ' .   I set on a test box and migrated my keys from my user account to the root user  reloaded ssh (service sshd reload) and it worked with those keys and my pem file with ssh -X -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ForwardX11=yes -i quick.pem root@x.x.x.x.  . It did not ask me for a password. Note, when testing sshd never log out lol . test with a new session.

Comment: I tried that earlier and nothing changed. I straight up copied the entire /etc/ssh folder from the old Pi to overwrite the /etc/ssh directory on the new Pi so everything would be exactly the same, but it didn't do anything. I hadn't tried reloading sshd though, so I tried that, but it said "sshd" was an unrecognized service. I did "service ssh reload" but that didn't change anything. Any other ideas?